# Showing/hiding panels in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

My app loads some HTML text (words + links) of the form:

```
<p>This OGR estimator is subject to the following <a class="collapsed">limitations</a> and <a class="collapsed">disclaimer</a>:</p>
<div id="limitations" class="collapse">...</div><div id="disclaimer" class="collapse">...</div><p>...</p>
```

I'm trying to create a directive that will "activate" the links to toggle the visibility of the targeted divs.  So far the directive can identify the links, but I'm stuck as to what to do next - and I'm also starting to suspect that my approach is jQuery-ish and thus need better direction.

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to (better) proceed.

Thanks/Tom

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'; 

@Directive({ selector: '[rewriteAnchors]' })

export class rewriteAnchors {

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
 const el = <HTMLAnchorElement>this.el.nativeElement;
 if (el) {  
   const links = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll("a.collapsed"))
   .map(l => (console.log(l),l))
   .forEach(l => l.addEventListener('click', this.doToggle(this)))
   ;
   }
 }

doToggle(me){
  return function doToggle(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   const targetid = this.getAttribute("href").replace("#","");
   console.log("target div = "+targetid);
   };
 }
}
```

Comment: `ngSwitch` is what you might be looking for. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_switch_directives.html

Comment: or you can create the `link` and `div` as it's own component.  Have a boolean flag to determine if the `div` is visible. use a `(click)` event to toggle the boolean flag.  Use *ngIf on the boolean flag to show hide the div.  I don't think you'd need to create a custom directive for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your input jmw. I can't, however, see how either suggestion will help me as the content containing the links and panels are loaded from the cms into the page.  Dividing that content into separate pieces seems a bit like the tail wagging the dog.  In other views within the app, cms content will be loaded containing only one hidden panel and one link, in other views, there may be more. So I need a generic solution - which is why I headed to a directive being applied after the view had been initialised.